# How to cut AC source using DC bias?

Tags: ac, coil

How to cut AC source using DC Bias (MOSFET or TRIAC or optocoupler)? Is that possible?
I use this circuit, but looks like the AC source not cut off or fully short.
[image]

Btw, this is secondary side from WPT, I want to cut or short the AC source by change the resonant value (you can see there is capacitor there that connect with optocoupler).

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by "cut AC source"? What's your goal?

Comment: You may need a separate source.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to cut or short the AC source by change the resonant value*

WPT (wireless power transfer) uses quite high resonance to achieve decent (sufficient) power levels in the receiver so, a simple opto just won't cut-the-mustard when used as a switch on the AC output of the receive coil. At the very least you need a more powerful device such as a MOSFET and, this can shift the receiver tuned circuit's resonant frequency by a reasonable amount.

However, because you are trying to "re-tune" an AC circuit, you would use back-to-back MOSFETs wired as a solid-state relay (SSR) to achieve this. There are devices available that can do this (if you just want to move the resonant frequency enough to detune the receiver a bit) but, if you want to "cut" the receiver's coil signal completely I believe you are going to be unlucky. Reason: as soon as this is "cut", the receiver loses power and inevitably "un-cuts" the solid-state-relay and power is restored again.